# Get an xhr document that loads when you visit a page

Tags: python-3.x, ajax, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I tried to obtain the elements that we can see below the photos on [the following site](https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/350870-oulong-atelier-cologne-oolang-infini.html) or on others, equivalent:

- https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/947895-oulong-xuecheng-atelier-cologne-orange.html
- https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/705357-pomelo-paradis.html
- https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/592260-cl-mentine-california.html
- https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/612353-oulong-atelier-cologne-trefle.html
- https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/911317-oulong-nimingmeigui-atelier-cologne.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But I can't get it from the source code. It is supposed to download dynamically with a javascript script. In fact it seems to be in an xhr document:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

So how can I get an xhr document that is downloaded when I visit a page?

I tried:

```
url = "https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/350870-oulong-atelier-cologne-oolang-infini.html"

r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

Pero me devuelve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-e72156ddb336> in <module>()
      2 
      3 r = requests.post(url, headers=headers)
----> 4 data = r.json()
      5 
      6 print(data)

3 frames
/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    355             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
    356         except StopIteration as err:
--> 357             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    358         return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the right headers and there you have the data.

```
import requests


headers = {
    "referer": "https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/350870-oulong-atelier-cologne-oolang-infini.html",
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
}
response = requests.get("https://www.nosetime.com/app/item.php?id=350870", headers=headers).json()

print(response["id"], response["isscore"], response["brandid"])
```

For some reason I can't paste the entire `JSON` output as `SO` thinks this is spam... o.O. Anyhow, this should get you the `JSON` response.

This prints:

```
350870 8.6 10091761
```

EDIT:

If you have more products, you can simply look over the product URLS and extract from the `JSON` what you need. For example,

```
import requests

product_urls = [
    "https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/947895-oulong-xuecheng-atelier-cologne-orange.html",
    "https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/705357-pomelo-paradis.html",
    "https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/592260-cl-mentine-california.html",
    "https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/612353-oulong-atelier-cologne-trefle.html",
    "https://www.nosetime.com/xiangshui/911317-oulong-nimingmeigui-atelier-cologne.html",
]


for product_url in product_urls:
    headers = {
        "referer": product_url,
        "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36",
    }
    product_id = product_url.split("/")[-1].split("-")[0]
    response = requests.get(
        f"https://www.nosetime.com/app/item.php?id={product_id}",
        headers=headers,
    ).json()
    print(f"Product name: {response['enname']} | Rating: {response['isscore']}")
```

Output:

```
Product name: Atelier Cologne Orange Sanguine, 2010 | Rating: 8.9
Product name: Atelier Cologne Pomelo Paradis, 2015 | Rating: 8.8
Product name: Atelier Cologne Clémentine California, 2016 | Rating: 8.6
Product name: Atelier Cologne Trefle Pur, 2010 | Rating: 8.6
Product name: Atelier Cologne Rose Anonyme, 2012 | Rating: 7.7
```

Comment: wait, what? Crazy SO. Thanks. Probably because it's Chinese and it thinks it's a virus ^^

Comment: LOL. Yeah, I guess so! :D

Comment: Do you know how I can get url you're using given the url I gave?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, but if the product URL looks the same for all products, just split by `/` and then `-` get the id number and put it in here `https://www.nosetime.com/app/item.php?id=`. Don't forget to drop the URL as referer too.

Comment: Or share a few product URLS and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Sure! I just shared a few